# Changed root password from '<blank>' to '<password>'. Now cannot connect to databases in Cloud SQL prompt

Tags: mysql

I changed the root password using [Google APIs SQL Prompt](https://code.google.com/apis/console) from blank to  using:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password = PASSWORD('<password>') WHERE user = 'root';
```

It has been documented [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access_control) that SQL prompt and some other APIs Services will lose functionality when a password is set on root. (Thanks for [Hasturkun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20270/hasturkun)'s comment below).

How then do we reset the password to `<blank>`?

Comment: @DanFromGermany, No,  The `Execute` Button at the Prompt itself is disabled.

Comment: Off topic probably belongs on [dba.se], also The [lovely documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access_control) has this to say: `Note that if you add a password to the root MySQL user, the APIs Console Interface will lose some functionality, including import and export capabilities, and the SQL prompt.`

Comment: @Hasturkun, How to revoke the password then?

Comment: I haven't the faintest, though you might be able to do so with the [command line client](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/commandline)

Comment: the password is stored hashed, that is why it is a **dumb idea** to change it using a sql statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to MySQL using current password and then you can change password like this

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost'=PASSWORD('');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now you can login MySQL using `BLANK` password.

This is not the most secure way to change password for better approach please have a look at [How to Reset the Root Password.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: Surprisingly, you could also say `SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost'='';` because `PASSWORD('')` is `''`. +1 !!!